# Add only files with extension to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a slideshow program, and part of that is adding image files.  To do this, I want to be able to search a selected folder for all files that have certain extensions.  I have looked, and I believe what I have below should work to pull in certain files.  However, in testing I find that it is pulling in every file, and not just ones with the proper extension.  Any help in figuring this out would be amazing, thank you!

```
def image_load_test(image_loop_path):
    image_file_table_length = 0
    path = image_loop_path
    image_file_table = []
    valid_images = [".gif",".png",".tga"]
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
            continue
        image_file_table.append(os.path.join(path,f))
        image_file_table_length = image_file_table_length + 1
        return image_file_table
```

I can tell this isn't working because I have a folder with many .png and .jpg images, and even though I am not adding .jpg to the valid_images table, those files still end up listed.

Comment: so `a.gif.foo` is a valid image name?

Answer (score 1):

@Nathan, the following code can help you  identifying the type of files

```
import glob
path_file = r'C:/Users/...' #path/folder of files where all the png files are kept
types = ('*.jpg', '*.png') #this is where you  add the required file type
all_files = []
for files in types:
    all_files.extend(glob.glob(path_file + files))
```

Comment: This would work, but I would like to have the ability to have a list of the file types I want to allow.

Comment: I have made the change to the code, you can define the file type and run the loop to get the files

Comment: Thank you, that would definitely work!  I also found a similar method messing with my existing code, but this looks much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Take out the 'not' from the if statement line, remove your 'continue' you don't need it, and put the next two lines where it is instead (tab them in).

Comment: Please add code instead of describing changes.

Comment: I tried those changes, no changes in resulting list, still has every type of file.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me, thank you everyone!

```
def image_load_test(image_loop_path):
    image_file_table_length = 0
    path = image_loop_path
    image_file_table = []
    valid_images = [".jpg",".png",".tga",".jpeg"]
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        if ext.lower() in valid_images:
            image_file_table.append(os.path.join(path,f))
            image_file_table_length = image_file_table_length + 1
            continue
        else:
            continue

    return image_file_table
```